# Add int to end of string name?

Tags: java, string, int

So I am looking for a way to temporarily store values so they can be deleted if necessary (I may be going about this the completely wrong way so correct me if I am wrong!)

I created 18 strings: info1, info2, info3, etc...

I want to set each one to a certain value dependent upon the hole the user is at, this is how I pictured it.

```
hole = 1;
info + hole = current; <--- current is a string with a value already.
hole++;
```

(so info1 = current value 1)

```
info + hole = current; <--- current is a new string with a new value similar to the first.
hole++;
```

(so info2 = current value 2)

If you need more code please let me know.  I decided I would skip it and not bother the community with the question so I deleted the code, and then decided no I really want this feature.  I will rewrite it real quick if its needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wrong approach

```
info + 1 = 2;
```

is not same as

```
info1 = 2;
```

You need to put things in an array and manipulate then

So for your 18 strings define an array as

```
String[] info = new String[18];
```

and then later do

```
info[hole-1] = current;
```

Here is the nice tutorial on basic arrays in java FYI http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It should be `info[hole-1] = current` since String arrays are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `String` array:

```
String[] info = new String[18];
// ....
hole = 1;
info[hole] = current;
hole++;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is syntactically wrong. You should use an array or list while dealing with a large number of variables. In this case, make a `String` array. This is how your code should look like:

```
String info[] = new String[18];
String current = "something";
int hole = 1;
info[hole-1] = current;  // string gets copied, no "same memory address" involved
hole++;
```

A shorter code snippet:

```
String info[] = new String[18], current = "something";
int hole = 1;
info[hole++ - 1] = current; // hole's value is used, THEN it is incremented
```

Go through [this official documentation tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) to learn more.